Is there a real difference between pragmatics and semantics in practice?
I am not sure where to draw the line between semantics and pragmatics. It appears that philosophers often attempt to solve a problem with regards to the use of language and suggest a theory that they presume to be semantic, and then they claim that the theory disproves other related theories, some of which are pragmatic in nature. When it is demonstrated that the theory fails to account for the usage of langugae on many different occasions, they flip the script and say It is a semantic theory that is ultimately concerned with how language works in its most fundamental form or something to that effect.
I felt this problem while reading Kripke's criticism of description theory and his causal theory of names;. Is the blurring line between pragmatics and semantics a big problem? Or is the difference well-established? Is there a grey area?

Wittgenstein was an early skeptic of splitting language use into literal meaning and practical deviations. Although the distinction gained popularity among analytic philosophers, they never agreed on where to draw it. Since 2000-s the skepticism returned, with many authors calling it a waste of time that does no work. Even Stotts, who defends it, admits "Different theorists use the terms ‘semantic’ and ‘pragmatic’ in different, often irreconcilable ways, which can sometimes be a symptom of terminology that ought to be retired."

Please either substantiate your general accusations with three or four examples or remove them.

The distinction is not a sharp one: pragmatics bleeds into semantics. But the distinction is still useful. Implicatures are an important feature of pragmatics and can be distinguished from meanings. Sarcasm, irony and metaphors can be understood as making pragmatic use of context to convey something different from the literal meaning of a sentence. Also, it would be difficult to describe the semantic side of logic if we could not separate it from pragmatic context.

"in theory, reality follows theory. In reality, however... '

You ask:

Is there a real difference between pragmatics and semantics in practice?

Yes, but you have to understand the notions of syntax, semantics, and pragmatics (SEP) are difficult to draw crisp borders around. My go to reference for the topic is Philosophy of Language (GB) by Szabó and Thomason. And we have to sort of delineate how the topics blend together.
Let's start with syntax. Syntax are essentially the rules of the code that manifest the Principle of Compositionality and map meanings onto symbols. The basic units of meaning have names like graphemes, morphemes, and lexemes (from smallest to largest), and syntax is how we assemble them. For instance, one seminal work on English syntax (and thus grammar) is James McCawley's The Syntactic Phenomena of English. Syntax, therefore is the foundation of semantics because it provides a literal understanding of equating the symbols with meanings.
This use of syntax, however is not entirely straightforward for a couple of reasons. For instance, meanings can be altered by use and abuse of such rules which are conventional, but not universal. In fact, different communities may have their own dialects in a broad sense. As a native to the Chicagoland area, I, for instance, have been heavily indoctrinated into the The Chicago Manual of Style (GB) because it's widely used geographically here. Another popular convention is the AP Style Guide (replete with its heinous views on the serial comma ;).
Secondly, even by following conventional syntax, there are still issues with conveying meaning because aspects of natural language are heavily context dependent. Three simple examples are reference, endophora, and deixis which respectively are locating identity attached to a token, locating sense attached to a token in the text, and locating sense attached to a token outside of the text. Natural language processing struggles with these sorts of tasks and has a toolbox to deal with these challenges, but human beings do it rather effortlessly.
Pragmatics then addresses an additional level of complication because the use of meaning can be effaced, non-literal, and indicate situational specific facts. As later Wittgenstein came to recognize, the nature of the words themselves are somewhat irrelevant and arbitrary when agents are attempting to achieve goals as part of a Sprachspiel. This is why human beings can speak Japanese, Finnish, or English, and still live relatively similar lives. The details of phonetics, grammar, and diction are actually beside the point. This feeds some aspects of linguistic relativity such as ontological relativism and quantifier variance.
In philosophical language, the locution itself may be immaterial as long as the illocutionary act and the perlocutionary force are brought about through the dialog. Now, obviously, the simplest way to avoid ambiguity and vagueness is to have a sophisticated grammar, which is a mental skill not even our closest Great Ape relatives can master (likely because of the neurological wetware required). This is why societies have complicated, natural-language grammars to help facilitate communicating intention, desire, knowledge, and the like. But strictly speaking, one needn't use one to do so. All that is required is shared intentionality. From WP:

Shared intentionality is a concept in psychology that describes the human capacity to engage with the psychological states of others. According to conventional wisdom in cognitive sciences, shared intentionality supports the development of everything from cooperative interactions and knowledge assimilation to moral identity and cultural evolution that provides building societies, being a pre-requisite of social reality formation.

Thus, it is also possible to communicate by ostention and inference by context, a point embraced by relevance theory. In fact, Sperber and Wilson argue that the semantics conveyed by the syntax is actually layered on top of the act of ostention-inference. In this way, implicature tends to play a very important an economical role in conversation since people who are familiar with each other are often knowledgeable enough to communicate without much in the way of explicature.
So, now we can answer. Semantics is a bit of a misnomer, because the division isn't so much between semantics and pragmatics, but implicature and explicature, which are better terms for conveying that some meaning is deliberately explicitly conveyed with utterances, and some is not. So, yes, there's an important difference because "semantics" is generally understood to be the explicatures embedded in syntax, and "pragmatics" which is generally understood to the implicatures carried in the head or signaled without the use of grammar. Part of the practical challenge of cognition is to know what is being said aloud, but then know that sometimes things are "read between the lines".

It is very much there in programming languages.

Semantics is the contents on the (implementation-independent) manual; preferably an ISO, ECMA etc standard.
PL pragmatics is about the gap between the semantics and implementations

the additions
the deviations
Non-functional aspects eg. modularity, portability, reliability, availability, security
"Best-practices" that follow from the above ie. "software engineering"




+1 Added a link to explanatory content. Feel free to roll back.

Tnx @JD  thought of doing similar. But then one would need an explanation for every 3rd word!! (For this audience). Even in a CS school, this would appear in a 2nd or 3rd year software engineering course, tying in preparatory material from many other courses. So a 2-3 para version could hardly do justice
